# How to Capture Response from 3rd Party Application back to Salesforce in Canvas App?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, callout, aura, canvas

**Requirement:** There's 3rd party application in our Organization which is used to upload the document. Once we upload the document in that application we want to fetch Document Id as Response back to Salesforce.

I have used below sample AURA component to display 3rd Party App within Salesforce:

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes, force:hasRecordId" access="global">
    <force:canvasApp developerName="Canvas_Aura" 
        height="1000px" width="1000px"
        parameters="{!v.canvasParameters}"/> // Passing Record Id as Parameters
</aura:component>
```

I want to know how Can I capture response(Fetch Document Id) from 3rd party app back to Salesforce Canvas App?

I am referring documentation about Canvas SDK(not sure if its helpful to capture response back to Salesforce) as it has an example of Heroku only but in Real Project we do not use Heroku.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_connect.meta/platform_connect/canvas_framework_using_sdk.htm?search_text=Canvas%20SDK

Can I make separate callouts in Parallel as soon as 3rd Party App uploads document within canvass App?

I would really appreciate response on this.

Comment: Is the canvas dispatching an event with the uploaded document Id? 
If yes, then you can add an event listener in the aura component. And get the Document Id from the event payload.

Comment: No. From Canvass application we will launch 3rd party API document upload form and once we upload document, 3rd party will send document id back to Salesforce which we need to capture in order to perform next operation